# Evaluating the integral to find the expected value of the exponential random variable

Tags: integration, probability-theory

I want to find the expected value of the exponential random variable.

I have $E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty }xae^{-ax}dx$.

I use Integration By Parts (IBP).

Let $v=-e^{-ax}\Rightarrow dv=ae^{-ax}dx$, and $u=v \Rightarrow du=dx$.

Then $E(X)=-xe^{-ax}_{(0,\infty )} + \int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-ax}dx$

I have been told that the first term would be $0$ since the exponential function goes faster to $0$ than to $\infty$ and the answer would be $\frac{1}{a}$.

My question is why does the exponential function in the first term goes faster to zero than it goes to infinity?

Comment: Because you forgot the negative sign on $e^{ax}$; it should be $e^{-ax}$.

Comment: @snarski Could you elaborate it? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $e^{ax} \geq 1 + ax + \frac{1}{2}(ax)^2$ for $a > 0$, 
$$xe^{-ax} = \frac{x}{e^{ax}} \leq \frac{x}{1+ax+\frac{1}{2}(ax)^2},$$
and this last term goes to 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced with the answer. I don't quite see how the last term goes to $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity. More details would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier to ask you: what do you know about limits, and have you heard of L'Hôpital's rule? (which I don't think you should use if you aren't comfortable with limits)

Comment: Yes, I've heard of L'Hopital's rule but it's been a while. Haven't really heard much of it in the real analysis course I took a year ago. So as you can tell I am a bit rusty.

Comment: Do you believe that the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ converges to 0? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, the sequence will converge to $0$ if I the take the limit of $a_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: I don't believe you. Why? [Notice that $\frac{x}{1+ax+(ax)^2} = \frac{x}{x}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + a + a^2x} \leq \frac{a^2}{x}$; if you believe $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \infty$, do you believe $\frac{1}{x} \rightarrow \infty$? $\frac{a^2}{x} \rightarrow \infty$?]

Comment: I was looking for a more intuitive explanation. See my answer.